# Text on Left, Icon on Right - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I position the icon to the far right and keep the text on the left with Bootstrap.

Here's my effort so far: https://www.bootply.com/5E2CGFEWdx

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success col-xs-12"> Call Us <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone push-right"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `float: right` to make your image stick to the right, and set the `text-align: left` so the text will start at the left end.

[Example here](https://www.bootply.com/G8GGeBTXW2)

```css
align-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.push-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success col-xs-12 align-left"> Call Us <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone push-right"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic - this worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend applying these changes to `button` in general (even less so since you're also using `!important`) , and changing what an actual Bootstrap class does `(.push-right`). This will have tons of unwanted side effects in any project with more than one developer working on it. Instead, create your own CSS class and use that for the necessary changes.

Comment: @connexo That's good advice. I'll be careful how I roll this snippet out. Thank you.

Comment: Content shouldn't be placed directly in row... *"Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows."*

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed it was quick and dirty.

Comment: `align-left` in your CSS must be `.align-left`.

Answer (score 3):

You can reposition the `span` holding the icon and make it `float: right;`:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.call-us {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.call-us span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success col-xs-12 call-us"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>Call Us</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
<style>
button {text-align:left}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success col-xs-12"> Call Us <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone pull-right"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `pull-left`, `pull-right` utility classes

```html
<html>
<head>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success col-xs-12">
      <span class="pull-left">Call Us</span>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone pull-right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 4 just need to use default float-right and text-left css classes like following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn text-left"> 
<span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-question"></i></span> ClickMe &nbsp;
</button>
```